# Firefox unicode boxes in selenium screenshot instead of characters

Tags: python, selenium, fonts, geckodriver

I'm using Firefox and Geckodriver on Ubuntu 20.04 (both on WSL2 and on a separate VM with similar results)

```sh
sudo apt install firefox -y

wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf geckodriver*
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/

# am using pipenv as a virtual env which brings in selenium
pipenv run python dm.py
```

Running a Python script to take a screenshot of a non EN character set gives me rectangles with (unicode addresses?)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1400, 2000)

driver.get("http://www.chinatoday.com.cn/")

time.sleep(1)

# fonts showing up as boxes with numbers
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

which saves as:

[image]

On regular firefox it uses the Microsoft YaHei fonts.

[image]

I've tried

```sh
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer -y

# update cache
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Have rebooted too which doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Found something on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/oc4mdb/selenium_webdriver_on_ubuntu_not_displaying/) about this. The poster claimed they fixed the issue by installing Noto Fonts:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto
```